# Wildcards in regular expression in directory paths for search/find?

Tags: java, directory, wildcard, subdirectory, jedit

This should be really simple. This directory `C:/ Users/matt/Documents/*/xyz123`
 should match any directory in `C:/ Users/matt/Documents/ "that contains a sub-directory"` called `xyz123`.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you can access files in the format given, and this is standard regular expression syntax, then you need a `.` before the `*`, as in:

```
C:/ Users/matt/Documents/.*/xyz123
```

`*` just means 0 or more of the preceding.
`.` stands for any character except for the new-line character